# empty df after using isin function

Tags: python, pandas

hello I'm trying to filter out df column that are contained in another dict

here is the sample:

```
import random
df = pd.DataFrame({'type': random.choice(['222', '44']), #let size be 10k for example
                   'method': random.choice(['open', 'close'])}) 
filter_dict = {'type': {0: ['44']}, 'method': {0: ['open', 'closed']}}
```

it works fine `with df[df['method'].isin(filter_dict['method'][0])]`

when i am trying to filter next column like this, i got an empty dataframe

```
df[df['type'].isin(filter_dict['type'][0])]
```

idk why it is happening, ty for ur answers

pandas version is 0.23.4

Comment: `df` is not a dataframe but a Series, so `df['type']` is a scalar and has no `isin` method. I imagine your real life data is more complex, please update the example.

Comment: @mozway my bad, sorry it is df, i ll chage it in a few seconds

Comment: Also, update your pandas version if possible. `0.23.4` is very old (2018).

Comment: @mozway cant update it rn, have to work with 0.23.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You example is invalid (you have a unique value with `random.choice`, thus the pandas error), but else, the code is working as expected:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'type': np.random.choice(['222', '44'], size=20),
                   'method': np.random.choice(['open', 'close'], size=20)})
filter_dict = {'type': {0: ['44']}, 'method': {0: ['open', 'closed']}}

df[df['type'].isin(filter_dict['type'][0])]
```

output:

```
   type method
1    44  close
2    44  close
4    44   open
5    44  close
6    44  close
7    44  close
8    44  close
9    44   open
10   44  close
13   44   open
19   44   open
```

If you want to test the condition on all columns:

```
mask = np.all([df[c].isin(filter_dict[c][0]) for c in df.columns], axis=0)
df[mask]
```

output:

```
   type method
4    44   open
9    44   open
13   44   open
19   44   open
```